# How to build a server database for my application

Tags: ios, database, server

I'm new to server side programming with a background in iOS. So I want to know where to start.

Here I tried to list some specific questions:

1. Can I just create a local database and practice on that?
2. Do the local databases and databases on remote server work the same?
3. If no, how can I choose which server I can use? (I went through the webpages of AWS cloud service and found they are really overwhelming.)

Comment: I can't fully address the specifics of your question but a server will likely be running a different database implementation than what you'll have available locally on the phone.  I'd imagine as far as a local database you could use SQLite, then find another SQL database to use remotely. You will have to rewrite some of the code that drives queries, but the queries themselves should be more or less the same if you keep to 'ordinary' SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arslan's answer is great, but I would like to add to it a bit. You mentioned a Chatroom, so in that case you should look into `socket programming`. The reason why I bring this up is, while no one has outright said it, you shouldn't create a chat server by read / writing to a database. It's much better to just keep it in memory and log to the database on an as need basis.

AWS is a fantastic solution and they have a lot of different solutions for different situations. You should look at using EC2, which is their server program. They have a free tier of it so that you can use and / or you can test locally. I suggest testing locally then pushing up to a free tier every now and then to make sure everything is running properly.

Also I would look into using CloudKit for data base storage. If you don't need instantaneous communication, it's far easier to use Apple's built in system rather than setup a server and manage it.

links: [CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/cloudkit-storage/), [AWS EC2 Free Tier](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/)

As it happens I'm actually working on a ChatRoom Server program, here's the link to [github](https://github.com/theMonster/ModularServer). It is written in `C++` so I recommend using it as a reference unless you want to write your own socket in `C++`.

Comment: Very good answer! So what you mentioned as different solutions AWS provide are real SDK that can be applied to my local test server?

Comment: @WebAmateur I'm a little confused by what your question is. AWS provides a type of service called EC2, which is a machine with a static IP that comes with basically any Os you want (my personal favorite Ubuntu).

Comment: So one more question, How can I test it locally? I just failed to configure a local server T T.

Comment: Checkout this tutorial, for installing a server locally on your Mac to test. http://www.lynda.com/Apache-HTTP-Server-tutorials/Installing-Apache-MySQL-PHP/77958-2.html

Answer (score 2):

> Can I just create a local database and practice on that?

Sure. You can install a server locally on your machine ( there are plenty of available ) and through 'localhost:3000' or 'localhost' you can access the root of your server depending upon what you are using at server end. You can then configure your server to respond to a particular message.

> Do the local databases and databases on remote server work the same?

Of course, the work they way is almost same. The difference you have stated yourself: **remote**.

> If no, how can I choose which server I can use? (I went through the webpages of AWS cloud service and found they are really overwhelming.)

I would suggest you to start from the local server. But first you have to choose language: PHP, Ruby, Python - it depends upon you and your personal preferences. You can also use something like [Parse.com](http://parse.com). Parse.com is free up to 30 requests/second, and you can use Objective-C to send and retrieve data from the server with a few very easy steps. And of course, parse.com handles singing up and logging in a user for you , all you have to do is to write a code of few lines in your iOS app.

Comment: Much clearer now! I've started to try to install a local test server on my mac first and test my code.

Answer (score 0):

Download Apple's free Server.app from the Appstore, it wraps one of the best database management systems: PostgreSQL. Start it with this Terminal command:

```
sudo serveradmin start postgres
```

More info on these pages:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5583

http://www.postgresql.org